# how to sort an array with a specific logic

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, logic

I wish to sort the following array in such way that the 'distance' between the events are the largest.

example:

```
events =  [[1,2],[2,8],[3,4],[1,2]]
```

the end result should be:

```
events =  [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4],[2,8]]
```

why?
consider [1:2] where x=1 and y=2
so x must comes first unless if y-x is larger then it should be pushed further away.
in the example it has [2:8] which means the distance is 6

what have I done?

```
events = sorted(events, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

result:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 8], [3, 4]]
```

but I couldnt figure our how to add another logic for the distance

Comment: Please better specify what those numbers represent and what "distance" means exactly?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to sort (x,y) pairs by `y - x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as you did, just sort by the delta between the numbers:

```
events = sorted(sorted(events), key = lambda x: x[1]-x[0])
```

Since Python's sort is a stable algorithm, first sorting normally ensures `[[1,2], [1,2], [3,4]]` will stay in that order, and then you can sort by distance.

```
>>> events =  [[1,2],[2,8],[3,4],[1,2]]
>>> events = sorted(sorted(events), key = lambda x: x[1]-x[0])
>>> events
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [3, 4], [2, 8]]
```

---

A different (but close) solution:

```
events = sorted(events, key = lambda x: (x[1]-x[0], x[0]))
```

I don't have a preference for either one. On timing tests both are quite similar on a 400-item list, but I guess it highly depends on starting conditions such as list size and list values:

```
py -m timeit -s "events = [[1,2],[2,8],[3,4],[1,2]]*100" "sorted(sorted(events), key = lambda x: x[1]-x[0])"
1000 loops, best of 5: 214 usec per loop
py -m timeit -s "events = [[1,2],[2,8],[3,4],[1,2]]*100" "sorted(events, key = lambda x: (x[1]-x[0], x[0]))"
1000 loops, best of 5: 220 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by two different things by making the key into a tuple. Is this what you're looking for?

```
events = sorted(events, key = lambda x: (x[1] - x[0], x[0]))
```

This sorts primarily such that those pairs with a larger difference will be at the end of the list and those with a smaller difference at the start. If negative differences can occur those will be the first. Secondarily, pairs with the same distance are sorted according to the first value.

Comment: He also wants to sort by the first term.

Comment: @Bharel OK. The question was quite unclear.

Comment: @Bharel I edited my answer. Now it's the same as your latter solution (which I think is the clearer one).